# KendoUI populate dropdown

Tags: kendo-ui

I am new to kendoUI and I need some assistance with getting the data that is returned from a function to populate into the dropdown.  I am currently getting [object HTMLSelectElement] - you can see in the image attached. Any help is appreciated.

[data is returned in function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWaUr.png)

[dropdown is not showing the years returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RCM8.png)

```
 LoadAcceptedSubmissionsGrid: function (module) {
        // Grid for "Accepted" tab
        var isAccepted = "true";
        gridAcceptedSubmissions = $("#gridAcceptedSubmissions").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                type: "json",
                serverPaging: true,
                serverSorting: true,
                serverFiltering: true,
                allowUnsort: true,
                transport: {
                    read: function (options) {
                        var strFilter = JSON.stringify(options.data.filter);
                        var strSort = JSON.stringify(options.data.sort);
                        var pageSize = options.data.pageSize === undefined && gridAcceptedSubmissions !== null ?
                            gridAcceptedSubmissions.dataSource.total() :
                            options.data.pageSize;
                        var acceptedSubmissionsUrl = commonUrl + "/Forms/Submissions/"
                            + upacsSessionId + "/" + userId + "/" + form + "/" + isAccepted + "/"
                            + options.data.page + "/" + pageSize + "/" + options.data.skip;
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: acceptedSubmissionsUrl,
                            xhrFields: {
                                withCredentials: true
                            },
                            data: {
                                filter: strFilter,
                                sort: strSort
                            },
                            success: function (response) {
                                options.success(response);
                            },
                            error: function (result) {
                                options.error(result);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                },
                pageSize: 10,
                batch: false,
                schema: {
                    total: function (response) {
                        return response.total;
                    },
                    data: function (response) {
                        return response.values;
                    },
                    model: {
                        id: "submissionId",
                        fields: {
                            state: { editable: false, type: "string", sort: "asc" },
                            fipsCode: { editable: false, type: "number", sort: "asc" },
                            year: { editable: false, type: "number", sort: "desc" },
                            name: { editable: false, type: "string" },
                            createdBy: { editable: false, type: "string" },
                            createdOn: { editable: false, type: "date" },
                            lastModifiedBy: { editable: false, type: "string" },
                            lastModifiedOn: { editable: false, type: "date" },
                            isEditable: { editable: false, type: "boolean" },
                            isReviewable: { editable: false, type: "boolean" }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            groupable: false,
            sortable: {
                showIndexes: true,
                mode: "multiple"
            },
            resizable: true,
            selectable: "row",
            scrollable: true,
            filterable: true,
            navigatable: true,
            pageable: {
                refresh: true,
                pageSizes: true,
                buttonCount: 10
            },
            dataBound: this.GridDataBound,
            columns: [
                {
                    field: "submissionId",
                    title: "Id",
                },
                {
                    field: "state",
                    title: "State",
                    filterable: {
                        multi: true,
                        dataSource: this.BuildMultiCheckboxDataSource("state", "name", true)
                    },
                    sort: "ascending"
                },
                {
                    field: "year",
                    title: "Year",
                    filterable: {
                        multi: true,
                        dataSource: this.BuildMultiCheckboxDataSource("year", null, true)
                    },
                    sort: "descending"
                },
                {
                    field: "status",
                    title: "Status",
                    filterable: {
                        multi: true,
                        dataSource: this.BuildMultiCheckboxDataSource("status", null, true)
                    }
                },
                {
                    field: "createdBy",
                    title: "Initiated By",
                    filterable: {
                        ui: this.FormCreatedByAcceptedFilter
                    }
                },
                {
                    field: "createdOn",
                    title: "Initiated On",
                    format: "{0:g}",
                },
                {
                    field: "lastModifiedBy",
                    title: "Modified By",
                    filterable: {
                        ui: this.FormLastModifiedByAcceptedFilter
                    }
                },
                {
                    field: "lastModifiedOn",
                    title: "Modified On",
                    format: "{0:g}"
                },
                {
                    title: "Action",
                    headerTemplate: "<div class='headerTemplate'><span class='headerText'>Action</span>" +
                        "<button class='clearAllFilters' id='clearAllFiltersAcceptedSubmissions' tabindex=0> Clear All Filters</button></div>",
                    command: [
                        {
                            name: "View",
                            text: " ",
                            visible: function (dataItem) { return !dataItem.isEditable },
                            template: function () {
                                var tmpl = "<a role='button' class='k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-View' title='View Form' tabindex=0>" +
                                    "<i aria-hidden='true' class='fa fas fa-eye'><span class='sr-only'>View form</span></i></a>";
                                return tmpl;
                            },                                    
                            click: function (e) {
                                e.preventDefault();
                                var data = this.dataItem($(e.target).closest("tr"));
                                $("#submissionId").val(data.submissionId);
                                commonFormsModule.UpdateFormMetadata(data, "from-grid")
                                gridSubmissionStatusHistory.dataSource.read();
                                commonFormsModule.SwitchTo("view-existing-form", module);
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            name: "View History",
                            text: " ",
                            visible: function (dataItem) { return !dataItem.isReviewable },
                            template: function () {
                                var tmpl = "<a role='button' class='k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-ViewHistory' title='View Form History' tabindex=0>" +
                                    "<i aria-hidden='true' class='fa fas fa-history'><span class='sr-only'>View form history</span></i></a> ";
                                return tmpl;
                            }, 
                            click: function (e) {
                                var data = this.dataItem($(e.target).closest("tr"));
                                $("#submissionId").val(data.submissionId);
                                commonFormsModule.UpdateFormMetadata(data, "from-grid")
                                gridSubmissionStatusHistory.dataSource.read();
                                commonFormsModule.SwitchTo("view-status-history", module);
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                },
            ]
        }).data("kendoGrid");
        gridAcceptedSubmissions.hideColumn(0);

        $("#clearAllFiltersAcceptedSubmissions").click(function () {
            gridAcceptedSubmissions.dataSource.filter({});
        });
    },
```

Comment: Please add the code for your grid to your post. Without that we can't see how your setting it up.

Comment: Hi ShawnOrr - I added the Grid code to the main description - thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing what `BuildMultiCheckboxDataSource` is doing, I can only make assumptions.

However, since you have declared year as an `IEnumerable<int>` then the datasource does not need to be anything elaborate. Simply set it to the collection being returned by the server:

```js
{
  field: "year",
  title: "Year",
  filterable: {
    multi: true,
    dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
      transport: {
        read: {
          url: "/my-endpoint-to-fetch-years-here"
        }
      }
    })
  },
  sort: "descending"
}
```